# Which is the best JavaScript library for wrapping the history API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

First, let me clarify I am talking about a website not an application as it's a simple website with three areas of content, no back end database and no back end coding.

What I want to achieve is a single page site so that using jQuery or another framework, I can slide the content in/out accordingly (I'm able to do this).  However I want the links not only to load the content but to do so like this:

```
www.address.com/Home
www.address.com/Services
www.address.com/Work
```

Easy with ASP.Net, but I imagine there is already a javascript framework out there that will do exactly this for me without the need for .net.  And if possible I would love to be able to load the content of each area when required.

Comment: Easy solution if you are on apache is to rewrite url hash values with htaccess. I guess you can rewrite with other web servers as well. (rewrite `www.address.com/Home to` `www.address.com/index.html#Home` as used in your one-pager)

Comment: Do you have a sample page which shows what you're trying to achieve? Your question is not entirely clear on what you want with the links

Comment: @jtheman — hashtags are a DSL for identifying search terms in a fragment of text. Don't confuse them with fragment ids on URIs.

Comment: Using fragment ids for determining what content to load [is problematic](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), I'd recommend against it.

Comment: @Quentin The arguments against it on a single web page is not surely sufficient even if you should regard it. Commonly used too.

Comment: Can't provide sample as not started it yet, doing my research on what I could use first.  I am essentially looking for js frameworks that will do it for me such as history.js, path.js or Sammy (which just been told about).

Comment: I like the way http://grooveshark.com/ works with the `http://grooveshark.com/#!/community`

Comment: Really frustrating when someone votes something down but doesn't leave an explanation, surely routing using a js framework is a perfectly reasonable topic???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) το to achieve what you want. it makes interfacing with the history api very easy

Comment: Exact sort of thing I'm looking for, also just discovered Sammy and Path.js which use #/Home instead of ?page=home.  Which would you recommend?

Comment: i have personaly only used history.js due to my dislike of hash values

Comment: keep in mind that you can do `History.pushState(null, null, "/Home")` since it doesn't matter what you have on your url but how you map that

Comment: Just now seen Davis.js which misses out the hash values (as I dislike them too, looks untidy in a URL) I will check out both of these, thanks.

Comment: there are many libraries for single page applications. which one you use depends on the complexity of your project.

Answer (score 0):

[Dial.js](http://danielteichman.github.io/Dial.js/) is a browser history framework built on jQuery with History.js. It simplifies browser history integration of event-driven interfaces and provides a simple alternative to MVC frameworks for single-page applications (SPAs).